How to enable automatically sending certain folders and file contents from one project to another different project
On Gitlab:
I have a project, called "First-Main-Project", I have a subproject called "Sub-Project". Within the subproject, I have a folder called "Files_All". Within that folder, I have another folder called "Listings", with various files.
(i.e, First-Main-Project/Sub-Project/Files_All/Listings)
I have a project, called "Master-Project", I have a subproject called "Sub-Project-2". Within the subproject, I have a folder called "Main-Listings". Within that folder, I have another folder called "All-Listings". Within that folder, I have another folder called "Listings-1".
(i.e, Master-Project/Sub-Project-2/Main-Listings/All-Listings/Listings-1)
I am trying to export the contents of the folder "Listings" within the project "First-Main-Project" into "Listings-1" within the project "Master-Project" using the Gitlab UI. I was thinking of using the .gitlab-ci.yml YAML File to do so that every time the pipeline runs, it will do that.
I am open to other suggestions. I have been reading the Gitlab documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html
But, it refers to exporting the whole gitlab project as a whole, not specific segments of the project. Furthermore, I'm trying to automate the process, and I can't find any other resources that are helping me figure this out, if it's possible.
I've also been looking at the potential to using Python scripts within the Gitlab environment.
Is it possible to do this? If so, how can I achieve this?
My Code:
stages:
  - sync

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: '-ffdx'

sync-listings:
  stage: sync
  image: alpine:latest
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add git
  script:
    # Configure git with the email and username of the user who triggered the pipeline
    - echo "Configuring Git user"
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}"
    
    # Clone the source project
    - echo "Cloning source project: First-Main-Project"
    - git clone (clone URL)
    - cd First-Main-Project/Sub-Project/Files_All/Listings
    - mkdir -p /tmp/listings
    - cp -r * /tmp/listings/
    - cd ../../../..
    
    # Clone the target project
    - echo "Cloning target project: Master-Project"
    - git clone (Clone URL)
    - cd Master-Project/Sub-Project-2/Main-Listings/All-Listings/Listings-1
    
    # Copy the listings from source to target
    - echo "Copying listings from source to target"
    - cp -r /tmp/listings/* .
    
    # Commit and push changes if any
    - git add .
    - if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then
        git commit -m "Sync Listings from First-Main-Project by ${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}";
        git push origin main;
      else
        echo "No changes to commit"
      fi
  only:
    - main


When you say "export" do you want to commit and push the files to the second project? Or will this only be needed in a pipeline of the second project?

By export, I mean commit and push the files to the second project.

Ok, what stops you from doing that? Can't you just checkout the second repository, copy the files there, commit and push?

It's unable to create a pipeline, I went ahead and added my code

Just one more question: You want to automate this process. Where should the automation pipeline run? Should First-Main-Project push the content to Master-Project or the other way around?

I was thinking that the automation pipeline run using the .gitlab-ci.yml file within the First-Main-Project (The Source of the files I want to copy over). The First-Main-Project push the content to Master-Project. I'm trying to copy all the contents/files within the Listings folder to the Listings-1 folder.
